# Get last logon time,computer and username together with Powershell

Tags: powershell, login, active-directory, user

I have a script which gets the last logon times of each computer in the domain.

My script:

```
$dcs = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem

foreach($dc in $dcs) { 
    Get-ADComputer $dc.Name -Properties lastlogontimestamp | 
    Select-Object @{n="Computer";e={$_.Name}}, @{Name="Lastlogon"; Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}
}
```

==================================

Result:

Computer    Lastlogon
--------    ---------
DC1         6/06/2013 16:38:24
DC2         6/06/2013 16:30:40

=============================================

I also want to get who/which account made this logon. For example:

Computer    Lastlogon            User
--------    ------------------   ----
DC1         6/06/2013 16:38:24   user2
DC2         6/06/2013 16:30:40   user1

Answer (score 4):

This one might not be perfect but it will get you on the right track. To get the exact last user, please see this [script](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-LastLogon-Determining-283f98ae). It will give you further information on how to filter the exact last user. In the below example, I have used, select-object -First 1 which should be a pretty good indicator of the last logged on user. To get the last logged on user, you need to use

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile
```

To 'join' the Get-ADComputer and Get-WMIObject information, I have used a Hash Table.

If you are running this from a Domain Administrator account, you can take the -credential $credential part out. Otherwise, leave it in and you can run it from a normal workstation with the RSAT tools installed so Get-ADComputer is available.

Code below:

```
$computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Server*' } -Properties OperatingSystem
$credential = Get-Credential -Message "Please enter your administrator username and password"

foreach($computer in $computers) { 
    $pcinfo = Get-ADComputer $computer.Name -Properties lastlogontimestamp | ` 
              Select-Object @{Name="Computer";Expression={$_.Name}}, ` 
             @{Name="Lastlogon";Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}}

    $lastuserlogoninfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer.name -Credential $credential | Select-Object -First 1
    $SecIdentifier = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($lastuserlogoninfo.SID)
    $username = $SecIdentifier.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

    # Create hashtable for properties
    $properties = @{'Computer'=$pcinfo.Computer;
                    'LastLogon'=$pcinfo.Lastlogon;
                    'User'=$username.value
                   } #end $properties
    write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $properties)
}
```

Check the formatting when you use it. Some of it I had to add in an escape (`) character to fit it into the script window.

Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Does not work, the `Expression` before `datetime` is marked read in VS Code.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out @Timo. Have updated with = . Should work now. Updating via mobile though so haven’t yet tested. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Maybe one curly brace is too much: `lastLogonTimestamp)}}`. One curly brace would be enough?

Comment: And: I am admin, so left the credential part out, but :  `$username = $SecIdentifier.Translate([System.Security.Principal.N …`. `Ausnahme beim Aufrufen von "Translate" mit 1 Argument(en):  "Manche oder alle Identit�tsverweise konnten nicht �bersetzt werden."`. Sorry for the german, there seems a Problem with `translate`.

Comment: Hi again @Timo I needed to add another curly brace just after the =. From https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object?view=powershell-6  - Example 10 - uses calculated properties. Sorry for any hassle this has caused. Thanks, Tim.

Comment: Now I get  `no constructor found` here: `$SecIdentifier = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($lastuserlogoninfo.SID)`. `lastuserlogoninfo` is empty. And: Get-WmiObject : RPC-Server not available. In Baramundi (Software Management Tool, I see the last logged on user. So there must be a server. Thanks Tim

Answer (score 3):

Not to burst everyone's bubble, but the "LastUseTime" field under Win32_UserProfile is NOT last Login; it's simply the last timestamp the "Profile" was updated (for any reason). You will find ALL profiles updated periodically for various reasons--installers, policy updates, etc.

Also, the data is not ordered by default, so the "-First 1" argument is not useful unless the data is first sorted by "LastUseTime"--which again is worthless due to above.

I hate to say that the above scripts are not providing any useful data for "Last Logon".

Answer (score 1):

This is Tim's Code and I updated it in order to display computer ip address & operating system, and export data.

```
 $computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter { OperatingSystem -NotLike '*Server*'} -Properties OperatingSystem

 foreach($computer in $computers) { 
     $pcinfo = Get-ADComputer $computer.Name -Properties ipv4Address, OperatingSystem ,lastlogontimestamp | 
               Select-Object @{n="Computer";e={$_.Name}}, 
              @{Name="Lastlogon";Expression={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.lastLogonTimestamp)}},ipv4Address,OperatingSystem

     $lastuserlogoninfo = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -ComputerName $computer.name -Credential $credential | Select-Object -First 1
     $SecIdentifier = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier($lastuserlogoninfo.SID)
     $username = $SecIdentifier.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount])

     # Create hashtable for properties
     $properties = @{'Computer'=$pcinfo.Computer;
                     'LastLogon'=$pcinfo.Lastlogon;
                     'ipv4Address'=$pcinfo.ipv4Address;
                    'OperatingSystem'=$pcinfo.OperatingSystem
                     'User'=$username.value
                    } #end $properties
     write-output (New-Object -Typename PSObject -Property $properties) |
     export-csv .\Computers.csv -append -notypeinformation -encoding "unicode"         
            }
```

[Powershell Get-ADComputer Properties Expression](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/0b50b004-c87a-4a36-80ce-eb5df36d1b1e/powershell-getadcomputer-properties-expression?forum=ITCG)

Comment: Please check your code.  Are there supposed to be back-ticks in it?  Hint: use Code Sample formatting rather than Block Quote.

Comment: Updated to code block